# Incremental refresh in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

When I watch my query it shows "View native query" is enabled:

[image]

But when I try to add incremental loading it still gives me a warning:
[image]

Should I just ignore it? Every single guide I've watched and read always tell that if you can open "View native query" it means it can be folded and incremental refresh will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether query folding is actually happens when you refresh the report. Depending on the data source you have you can use couple of methods described here: https://youtu.be/QEFze-LdLqo.

If you use Google BigQuery (possible in other databases as well) you should also be able to see queries that were actually performed in your database.

If you have proper query folding you shouldn't have any problem with using incremental refresh. View Native Query can even be disabled, but query folding might still happen under the hood. So it always better to check what's the query in your database in any case, just to be sure.